# How to use make_unique in omnet++ 5.5.1

Tags: c++

Im using omnet++ Version: 5.5.1 
and using:
K:\omnetpp-5.5.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin>g++ --version
g++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.1.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

code:

```
auto p1 = std::make_unique<double>(3.14);
```

error: 'make_unique' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: Im using #include <memory>

Comment: Do you have a C++14 compliant compiler? Maybe you need to use a compiler flag?

Comment: Are you using a compiler that supports C++14 or later and have you enabled that support?

Comment: How can i check if omnet++ is C++14 ?

Comment: Im using in configure.user file : CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14

Comment: thank, Im solve problem by change CXXFLAGS=-std=c++14 in  configure.user file